# Paypal Hosted Solution (Iframe) - Wrong Language

Tags: payment, paypal, iframe

I have found out this bug for Paypal HHS.

If the mercant location is set to italian, in the checkout page I have an Iframe hosted by paypal.

The issue is that the iframe come out always in Italia for all Store Views.

Any idea about how to deal with this ?

is it possible to add a parameter in the Iframe Url, to force a specific language ?

**Reference Files**:

- app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Block/Hosted/Pro/Iframe.php
- app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Block/Iframe.php
- app/design/frontend/base/default/template/paypal/hss/iframe.phtml

https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/hostedsolution_uk.pdf

Comment: Francesco, maybe does this help? https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/website-payments-pro/hosted-iframe-language-any-parameter http://blog.brains4all.com/brainblog/archives/2008/04/paypal_language.html

Comment: lc = 'US' works fine, however this is bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is a bug of paypal extension `lc` variable is set on the base of Mercant Country so in my case it is `IT`.

Take a look at this file `Mage_Paypal_Model_Hostedpro_Request` method `_getPaymentData` (135):

```
        'lc'            => $paymentMethod->getMerchantCountry(),
```

So I need to make this dynamic on the base of store view.

I found out that the right value for me are `IT` and `US` for english.

Here other language code:
http://blog.brains4all.com/brainblog/archives/2008/04/paypal_language.html

US
GB
NL
DE
IT
FR

Answer (score 1):

in line 135 replace with:

```
'lc'            => substr(Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode(),3),
```

this will fetch you the set language for the store view. the output would be, for example: en_US.
With substring you get US or IT.

Make sure that in the Magento Backend in System > Configuration > General the Locale is set to "English (United States)"

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Merchant Location for the 'Website'?

We had this problem with a French and German 'Store View' that were under the same 'Website'. The Merchant Location can only be set at a Global or Website level in Magento. So, we had to remove the 'Store View' for the German site and create it as a 'Website'. This allows us to set the Merchant Location to France for the French Website and Germany for the German website.

This is a link to Magento User Guide that helped us:

http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/payment/merchant-location.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: check my answer below